# Паттерн для работы со строкой

Tags: java

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Q3 {

    public static double withregexp(String str) {
        double rez = 0;
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[-? 0-9]+[.][0-9]+"); // паттерн для 
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {             // определения строки
            for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length() + 1; j++) {
                String comp = str.substring(i, j);
                Matcher mat = pat.matcher(comp);
                boolean b = mat.matches();
                if (b == true) {
                    System.out.println(i + " " + j + "         " + comp);
                    rez = Double.parseDouble(comp);
                }           
            } 
        }

        return rez;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "qwerty34.34abcd 34.30";
        System.out.println(withregexp(s));
    }
}
```

output:

> 6 10         34.3
>
> 6 11         34.34
>
> 7 10         4.3
>
> 7 11         4.34
>
> 15 20          34.3
>
> 15 21          34.30
>
> 16 20         34.3
>
> 16 21         34.30
>
> 17 20         4.3
>
> 17 21         4.30
>
> 4.3

Проблема заключается в том, что метод `Double.parseDouble(comp)` игнорирует пробелы в начале и в конце строки. Поэтому это ограничение нужно задать в паттерне — без первого символа пробела. Попробовал все вариации спецсимвола `/s`. не получилось.
То есть паттерн должен не давать пройти строке `" 34.3"` и `" 34.30"`

Comment: мне как-то сложно понят, что тут происходит, алгоритм слишком сложный, неправильный, непонятный, отсюда и сложности с паттерном

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в начале паттерна добавить отрицание пробела - **^(\x20)**